# I want to avoid to recreate the AppBar and Drawer when I change the tool that I am using

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am creating an app that has by default the google map satellite view at the center of the application, but I have other tools in my app, so I would like to keep the same AppBar and the same Drawer in all screens, avoiding to create it over and over again. The only thing that I would like to change is the satellite view so that the space occupied by the map would fit another tool's functionalities.

Is there a way to create only once the AppBar and Drawer and fit other tools' screens in the space of the map without needing to recreate the AppBar and Drawer many times?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Within a scaffold, set the body to be an AnimatedSwitcher, and have the child be a variable. Any time you wish to change the satellite view out for another widget, call SetState and change the child variable.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: MyAppBar(), //This will never change
        body: DynamicContainer(),
    );
  }

  ChangeWidget() {
    myChangingWidget = Container();
  }
}

class DynamicContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  DynamicContainer({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _DynamicContainerState createState() =>
      _DynamicContainerState(controller: controller);
}

class _DynamicContainerState extends State<DynamicContainer> {
  Widget _myAnimatedWidget;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _myAnimatedWidget = myListOfWidgets[0]; //The widget it will start as
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedSwitcher(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      child: _myAnimatedWidget, //Our dynamic widget
    );
  }

  switchWidget() {
    setState(() {
      _myAnimatedWidget =
          myListOfWidgets[1]; //Where you change the widget
    });
  }
}
```

This will redraw the body while maintaining your AppBar and Drawer. Check out the official Flutter video on AnimatedSwitcher - https://youtu.be/2W7POjFb88g

**Code Snippet has been updated and should be correct.

Comment: Sorry, Andrew, this is a project that I was working on my vacations, I will test it next month when I will be free of work. I am so sorry that I could answer you before :(